# Capture All Wi-fi Networks and save into list

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, network-protocols

### Obtain Wi-Fi Networks using CoreWLAN Cocoa Library

I'm trying to obtain a list of Wi-Fi networks that my current mac can see using the CoreWLAN library but to no avail. I've been using [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008921-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from their website.

What I'm looking for specifically is a list (array) of:

- Available Network Names
- Their Password/Encryption type

Here is my code which is apparently deprecated now, and does nothing at all when I `NSLog("%@", currentNetworkName)`:

```
self.currentInterface = [CWInterface interfaceWithName:[CWInterface supportedInterfaces];
NSString *currentNetworkName = nil;
currentNetworkSSID =  [self.currentInterface ssid];
```

Thanks for All your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CoreWLAN Framework.

Here is some sample code tested on Mavericks (10.9.1)

```
CWInterface* interface = [[CWInterface alloc] initWithInterfaceName:@"en1"];
    NSError* error;
    NSSet* wifi = [interface scanForNetworksWithName:nil error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    } else {
        [wifi enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            CWNetwork* net = (CWNetwork*)obj;
            NSLog(@"%@", net.ssid);
         }
    }
```

The CWNetwork class has a method to check security :

```
- (BOOL)supportsSecurity:(CWSecurity)security;
```

with CWSecurity :

```
enum {
   kCWSecurityNone = 0,
   kCWSecurityWEP = 1,
   kCWSecurityWPAPersonal = 2,
   kCWSecurityWPAPersonalMixed = 3,
   kCWSecurityWPA2Personal = 4,
   kCWSecurityPersonal = 5,
   kCWSecurityDynamicWEP = 6,
   kCWSecurityWPAEnterprise = 7,
   kCWSecurityWPAEnterpriseMixed = 8,
   kCWSecurityWPA2Enterprise = 9,
   kCWSecurityEnterprise = 10,
   kCWSecurityUnknown = NSIntegerMax,
};
```

Comment: supportsSecurity could return YES on few options. So it doesn't give information about current security mode.

Comment: Your code gives an error that it's missing a close square bracket.

Comment: This is a code extract, it is not supposed to run "as is".  For clarity, I added two missing brackets however.  Thank you for your feedback